# Laravel Get data One to Many Relationship with conditions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

how to display data one too many relationships with conditions into view.

I have a blog post that has a comment, but this comment has a condition that published or not.

here my `Post` Model

```
...

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
...
```

on my code above I can simply use `$post->comments` to show all the comments.

like I said before, I need only show comments with published is `true`

but how to add conditions?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by getting the post with it's published comments;

```
$post = Post::where('id', $id)->with('comments', function ($q) { 
     $q->where('published', true);
})->first();
```

Then when in the view you call $post->comments, you will only get the published one.

Alternatively, if you really want to you can update your Model to have a published comments relationship, but this is less advised.

```
public function publishedComments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->where('published', true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get only published comments by using
`$this->post->comments()->where('published', true)->get()`

Check the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

> Of course, since all relationships also serve as query builders, you can add further constraints to which comments are retrieved by calling the comments method and continuing to chain conditions onto the query: `$comment = App\Post::find(1)->comments()->where('title', 'foo')->first();`